# UTF8 arrow symbols: Which package to use?

Tags: pdftex, arrows, unicode

I have this mwe to show that the U+1F83A does not yet work in pdflatex. What do I have to add?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
(Shh)
\end{document}
```

Is there any package which provides the small arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar symbol in Zapf Dingbats. See `texdoc pifont`, table 2. It's in slot 225, but you probably want it smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{}{\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{225}}}

\begin{document}

 xyz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the scale factor to your liking.

Comment: that looks nice. Do you know whether it is possible to shrink the symbol horizontally, but not vertically?